# Генерация события на элементе формы JS

Tags: javascript, события

Здравствуйте интересует вопрос как вызвать событие на чекбоксе формы
что бы ввести в консоль и появилась галочка.

```
var elem = document.forms[0][0]
var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents')
event.initEvent("change", false, false);
elem.dispatchEvent(event)
```

так не работает, и следующие тоже не работает:

```
elem = document.forms[0][0]
var event = new Event("change");
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Но как я понимаю последний вариант это установка кастомного события, но в то же время программный сабмит формы работает:

```
elem = document.forms[0]
var event = new Event("submit");
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Да и с чекбоксом не только `change`, но `focus` не неработает его (конструкция:`var elem = document.forms[0][0]; elem.focus()` вообще возвращает undefined).

Что я делаю не правильно? Как вызвать chande на чекбоксе или фокус хотя бы?

P.S. как это сделать на JQuery знаю, интересует чистый JS (браузер Chrome).

Comment: Затупил change это же когда уже изменено вызывается, но в фукусом по прежнему не ясно

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что событие change не работает? добавь обработчик этого события, и увидишь, что все работает

Comment: Согласен, оно работает. Впрочем как и onfocus но визуально фокус не отображается, при этом кликая табом, чекбокс загорается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вопросе перепутаны причины и следствия.

События возникают **после** того, как действия произошли, поэтому просто вызвав событие, ничего не произойдет, кроме вызова обработчика этого события, если он был.

Из-за этого кажется, что событие `change` не происходит. Для того, чтобы вручную поменять состояние чекбокса, необходимо менять ему [свойство checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties), если нужно чтобы после этого вызвались обработчики, нужно послать соответствующее событие.

```js
elem = document.forms[0][0]
elem.onchange = function() {
  console.log('change event');
}
elem.checked = true;
var event = new Event("change");
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" />
</form>
```

С фокусом немного иная ситуация, так как у элементов, есть непосредственный [метод *focus*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Methods)

```js
elem = document.forms[0][0]
elem.onfocus = function() {
  console.log('focus event');
}
elem.focus();
```

```css
input:focus + span::before {
  content: 'focus';
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span></span>
</form>
```

Comment: В моём FF не работает...

Comment: что именно? и какая версия FF?

Comment: Второй сниппет. FF 50 beta 4, например. А в хроме работает.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
  console.log(event.target.checked, '(from handler)');
});

console.log(input.checked);
input.click();
console.log(input.checked);
```

```html
<input type=checkbox>
```